# Use scala List and Enumeration in Java

Tags: java, list, scala, enumeration

i couldn't find a solution for this problem:

i have this scala code

```
package testScala

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable._

object TypeEnum extends Enumeration {
  type TypeEnum=Value
  val A, B, C, D, E = Value
}

import TypeEnum._

case class Foo(param1: TypeEnum, param2: List[Int]) {
  def length: Int = param2.length
}
```

Java code:

```
package testJava;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

import testScala.TypeEnum;
import testScala.Foo;



public class testJava {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        List<Object> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add(1);
        l1.add(2);

        //Error here
        Foo f = new Foo(TypeEnum.A(), JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(l1).toList());

    }
}
```

i get the error "The constructor Foo(Enumeration.Value, List) is undefined".

how can i instantiate a new object from type `Foo` (with a non-empty list)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When in doubt, I would run javap on the created .class file. That would tell you at least which names/methods exists for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this

scala file:

```
package test

object TypeEnum extends Enumeration {
  type TypeEnum=Value
  val A, B, C, D = Value
}

import TypeEnum._

case class Foo(param1: TypeEnum, param2: List[Int])
```

java file:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.List;
import test.TypeEnum;
import test.Foo;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(TypeEnum.A(), null);
        System.out.println(foo.param1());
    }
}
```

But maybe better don't. Using scala from java can be a pain, expecially when you put scala collections in the api.

Note that by convention you should start name of your classes with capital letter, and you shouldn't put `val` for fields of case classes as they are added implicitly anyway.

### Edit

To answer the comment, I extended `Foo` with `sum` method for test.

```
case class Foo(param1: TypeEnum, param2: List[Int]) {
  def sum = param2.sum
}
```

You were converting it right but from javas point of view, `Foo` needs `List<Object>`, so you need your `ArrayList` to contain `Objects`.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(4);
Foo foo = new Foo(TypeEnum.A(), JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list).toList());
System.out.println(foo.param1());
System.out.println(foo.sum());
```

So to get your way from `ArrayList<Integer>` to `ArrayList<Object>` I think you need to create a new `ArrayList<Object>` and readd all elements. As I said earlier very dirty stuff. Better just create a scala wrapper that takes java type and converts and delegates the list.

### Edit

As the code you presented works for me maybe you have something else causing the problem. I simply created sbt project with 2 files, using scala 2.11.8 and it compiles.

Here is the adapter class I mentioned before

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
class FooAdapter(param1: TypeEnum, param2: java.util.List[Integer])
  extends Foo(param1, param2.asScala.map(_.intValue).toList)
```

it will let you to pass just an `ArrayList<Integer>` from java.

Comment: thanks for the answer. using the enumeration this way works, but i couldn't figure out how to convert a java list to a scala list. i tried to create an object with this line: `Foo f = new Foo(TypeEnum.A(), JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(l1).toList());` where `l1` is a not empty  ArrayList

Comment: sorry, i keep get this error: "The constructor Foo(Enumeration.Value, List<Object>) is undefined" or "The constructor Function(Enumeration.Value, List<Int>) is undefined"

Comment: Can you edit your question with the minimal example that contains both java and scala code you are trying to use? Also I will repeat this again: don't  do this, you will only suffer :p

Comment: Thanks for your help Łukasz, i appreciate it. My only problem is to use the class "Foo" in java. After i have figured it out i will never have to deal with scala again and i can go back to my beloved language C++ :D

Comment: I built up simple sbt project with 2 files you provided and it compiles and runs, no problem. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The Scala enumeration is an `object`. Like any `object` it can be used from Java using the suffix `$.MODULE$`

```
TypeEnum$.MODULE$.A()
```

Comment: Scala compiler also generates static members for objects, so `TypeEnum.A()` is going to work.